# R Shiny How to indicate stale state when inputs have changed but score has not updated

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I have a shiny app with many inputs & a scoring function. There is no action button per se. Any input change triggers a re-score.

Sometimes a user has changed the input but it takes the score some time to update. This may mislead the user in associating the new state with the old score.

I want to fix this by having some display cue e.g. a *"Score is being computed"* message or gray out UI etc. dynamically whenever the score shown is stale.

How do I achieve this? Any thoughts?

```
fn_run<-reactive({
    scorer(inputs......)
})

  output$score<-renderPrint(cat(fn_run()$score))




                sidebarPanel(title="Scoring Outputs",width = 3,
                          h3(textOutput("title")),
                          h3(textOutput("score"),style="color:blue"),
)
```

Mostly the delay is discernible when I publish the app to shinyapps.io and not palpable on local shiny runs.

Comment: It depends how the score is being calculated, but you can make use of a [`progressBar`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/progress.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some CSS and the shinyjs package.

The following blog has what I think you want:

http://deanattali.com/blog/advanced-shiny-tips/

The relevant code is found here:

https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/blob/master/loading-screen/app.R

This will show you how to shade the whole screen whilst the app is loading.